# Was the big bang a black hole that collapsed

Tags: black-holes, big-bang

I know this might be a silly question and maybe a bit off topic, but I wonder, could the big bang have been the collapse of a gigantic black hole in which all off its contents was pushed out? I have only basic skills in physics so I feel a bit embarrassed to ask. I could imagine a cycle of black holes collecting matter, merging with other black holes and when reaching some limit, spewing it all out, just to be collected by other black holes in the future

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce

Comment: What if the big bang just took place in a part of the universe? If we suppose that universe is infinite, maybe some parts were unaffected, but they might be too far off to see?

Comment: The universe is not infinite. In fact, the Big Bang Theory describes the expansion of the universe from a singularity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe#Size_and_regions